# Change Sinatra views directory location

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'd like to structure a Sinatra application more like a Rails application with the following structure:

```
.
├── app
│  ├── models
│  │   └── a_model.rb
│  └── views
│      └── a_view.erb
└── app.rb
```

According to the [documentation](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html), it can be done by overwriting the `:views` setting:

> `:views` **- view template directory**
>
> A string specifying the directory where view templates are located. By default, this is assumed to be a directory named “views” within the application’s root directory (see the `:root` setting). The best way to specify an alternative directory name within the root of the application is to use a deferred value that references the `:root` setting:
>
> `set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }`

I've setup `:root` and `:views`:

```rb
set :root,  File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, 'app', 'views') }

# Also tried some variations like:
# set :views,        'app/views/'
# set :views,         Proc.new { File.join(setting.root, 'app', 'views' }
# set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, 'app', 'views' }
# ...

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :a_view
  end
end
```

But I'm always facing the same error message:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /path/to/my/app/views/a_view.erb
```

Indeed, `settings.views` is evaluated to `/path/to/my/app/views` (instead of `/path/to/my/app/app/views`)

It looks like I cannot control the value of the `:views` (`settings.views`) variable. I know I could simply move the views folder to the root location.

Can anyone explain why I'm not able to control theses settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move settings inside class definition has all the settings are inherited from inside Sinatra::Base

```rb
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :root,  File.dirname(__FILE__)
  set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, 'app', 'views') }

  get '/' do
    erb :a_view
  end
end
```

Or

```rb
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :root,  File.dirname(__FILE__)
    set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, 'app', 'views') }
  end

  get '/' do
    erb :a_view
  end
end
```